# Is it it possible to have the Rails Asset Pipeline compile Coffeescript on every request?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, asset-pipeline

I'm building a JS widget using Coffeescript. I'm playing some tricks to get my CSS/SCSS and HTML/HAML templates into the JS widget upon compilation:

```
# widget.js.coffee.erb
class Widget
  constructor: (options) ->
  @template = <%= Haml::Engine.new(
    File.read(
    File.expand_path("../../templates/widget.html.haml", __FILE__))).
    render.to_json %>

  @css = <%= Sass.compile_file(
    File.expand_path("../../stylesheets/widget.css.scss", __FILE__)).
    to_json  %>
```

The problem is that when I change the HTML or CSS, Rails is not recompiling the Coffeescript in development because the coffeescript file is not changing. I need to make silly whitespace changes to force it to recompile things. This is getting annoying :-)

Any ideas on how to force the asset pipeline to compile certain files on every request?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got it. Sprockets has a [depend_on](https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets#the-depend_on-directive) directive. Adding the following lines to my widget.js.coffee.erb solved it:

```
# coffee.js.coffee.erb
#= depend_on '../templates/widget.html.haml'
#= depend_on '../stylesheets/widget.css.scss'

class Widget
...
```